# ActiveMQ jndi.properties java.naming.referral

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ's [LDAPLoginModule](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/trunk/activemq-jaas/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/jaas/LDAPLoginModule.java?revision=1069405&view=co) doesn't like the LDAP searchResRef generated by my AD server when searching the root of the LDAP tree. It generates (a swallowed):

> NamingException javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s);

I need to set the `java.naming.referral` property to `follow`. I can change the source by adding:

> env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

But, is there a way to use the mystical (to my C# brain) [jndi.properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html) file to avoid a recompile?

### More Info

The command line used to start the process:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx256M 
-Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/root/apache-activemq-5.5.0/conf/login.config 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dactivemq.classpath=/root/apache-activemq-5.5.0/conf; 
-Dactivemq.home=/root/apache-activemq-5.5.0 
-Dactivemq.base=/root/apache-activemq-5.5.0 
-jar /root/apache-activemq-5.5.0/bin/run.jar start
```

The bit of existing code I want to influence (isLoginPropertySet and getLDAPPropertyValue just read from an ActiveMQ config file - login.config in the above commandline):

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, getLDAPPropertyValue(INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY));
if (isLoginPropertySet(CONNECTION_USERNAME)) {
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, getLDAPPropertyValue(CONNECTION_USERNAME));
}
if (isLoginPropertySet(CONNECTION_PASSWORD)) {
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, getLDAPPropertyValue(CONNECTION_PASSWORD));
}
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, getLDAPPropertyValue(CONNECTION_PROTOCOL));
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, getLDAPPropertyValue(CONNECTION_URL));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, getLDAPPropertyValue(AUTHENTICATION));
context = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just put `java.naming.referral=follow` into a text file named `jndi.properties` and locate that in the root directory of your JAR file.

To add to a jar file:

`jar -uf run.jar jndi.properties`

Comment: I created jndi.properties and placed it into the /bin folder with run.jar. It doesn't seem to pick that up. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mark Brackett: No, put it *inside* the jar file, in the root directory.